# jupyter nbconvert register jinja filter

Tags: filter, jinja2, jupyter, nbconvert

For the jupyter sas_kernel I'm writing a template for nbconvert (version 4.2.0). The basic layout is as follows:

```
{%- extends 'null.tpl' -%}
{#  Comment block #}

{% block header %}
/* coding: SAS utf-8 */
{% endblock header %}

{% block in_prompt %}
/* In[{{ cell.execution_count if cell.execution_count else ' ' }}]: */
{% endblock in_prompt %}

{% block input %}
{{ cell.source | ipython2python | sas_magic_regex }}
{% endblock input %}

{% block markdowncell scoped %}
/*
{{ cell.source | comment_lines(prefix='*') }}
*/
{% endblock markdowncell %}
```

In the block input section I need to use a regular expression to process the text from `ipython2python` mostly to deal with magic calls. I couldn't see a regex function from the [string filers](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/filters/strings.py)
so I wrote my own:

```
def sas_magic_regex(string:str) -> str:
    """ Replace Python Magics with a commented out version or the SAS x command """
    sas_magic=re.compile(r'^get_ipython.*?(\w+)\(\'(.*)\'\)')
    newStr=sas_magic.search(string)
    if len(newStr.groups())==2:
        if newStr.group(1)=='system':
            return 'x ' + newStr.group(2) + ';'
        else:
            return '/* Jupyter magic ' + string + ' */'
env = Environment()
env.filters['sas_magic_regex'] = sas_magic_regex
```

The problem is that nbconvert can't find this jinja filter.
I get this error message: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'sas_magic_regex'`

Comment: You have probably seen this, but the [docstring of the `TemplateExporter` class](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/cc7a2dd7ccb430c3545b153a5790cf7c289eb4e3/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py#L61) says to inherit from it in order to add filters.